# First query slow on Firebird

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, performance, firebird

The first query run on a large dataset on a Firebird database after starting our application is always very slow. Subsequent calls to the same query (it is a stored procedure) are fine. I assume that this is to do with something being loaded into memory but I could do with a explanation of what and whether there is anything that can be done to get around the issue.

Comment: Every query, no matter what the query?  Or a particular query? Does the SP create a SQL statement dynamically? Is the Firebird db not started until you start your client app? Normally the application and the db are independent of one another.

Comment: To answer questions: No, just 1 query. No, it doesn't dynamically create sql. yes, fb is started and running all the time. They are independent. I would post the sp but it is too long for the number of chars allowed here.

Comment: You can post it eg to http://pastebin.com/ ?

Comment: I can! It is here: http://pastebin.com/0dFg4y12

Comment: @williamsdb could you post the query again (within the question). Thx.

Comment: @wolf No as I left the company I was working for when this was an issue three years ago.

Answer (score 1):

If is a stored procedure the first query it compiles the stored procedure also it fetches the buffers and caches the result. 
On the second query the procedure is not compiled again (precached) and the results are instant (the fetches are also in memory for some operating systems so no need for disk io)

one way is to optimize the sp or the tables 
How larger are they? (number of records for each table)

one simple way to optimize this is to put a cron script that will run once per day/hour to prefill the caches so you will get fast sp

Comment: I did wonder about this. I know that SQL Server compiles and caches SPs in memory and so can be slower the first time. I will try the suggestion of scheduling the SP. As for the number of records, there are two SPs and two tables with about 200,000 records in each. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not about the query, but the connection time (delay) is long? There was such a problem with [old] Firebird/Interbase engines.

Comment: Maybe you mean the problem related with the file extension, .gdb is a "system special extension" in xp (and presumably later windows versions), so the operating system makes a full copy of the database file when the engine first opened it.  AFAIK, the problem is still present and is not related to the engine itself.  If you still use a .gdb extension for a database file the first connection will be slow regardless of the firebird/interbase version you're using.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the thoughts. We are using Firebird v2.1 on Windws Server 2003 and the database extension is .fdb. The db size is 5gb so if a full copy was being made that would take a time. But given that the extension is fdb does this not apply?

Comment: Checking the Microsoft "monitored" list (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378870(VS.85).aspx) fdb is not on it so, unfortunately, that cannot be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain which Firebird version you are using but, in version 2.50, there is a bug (CORE 3227 - slow compilation of stored procedures) that can be the cause of your problem. More details:
http://www.firebirdnews.org/?p=5282&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+FirebirdNews+%28Firebird+News%29

Comment: Hi thanks for the pointer. We are currently using FB v2.1 so maybe I won't rush to upgrade!